# ARKit – Light Estimation

Tags: swift, abstract-class, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am getting an error about `init()` not being available for `ARLightEstimate`.

Code:

```
class LightSensorManager {

    let lightEstimate = ARLightEstimate()  // <-- error is here
    var ambientLightIntensity: CGFloat

    init() {
        ambientLightIntensity = lightEstimate.ambientIntensity
    }
}
```

Error:

```
/*   'init()' is unavailable    */
```

[API to ARLightEstimation - ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arlightestimate)

I assume it is an abstract class? But I cannot find a concrete subclass of it. I only want to use the ambient Light sensor from this API to detect ambient Light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's how you can use `Light Estimation` in ARKit – [Full code version is HERE](https://medium.com/@arkit/arkit-911-light-estimation-e10adf49ab32):

- Enable Light Estimation in viewWillAppear(_:) instance method:

  ```
   let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
   configuration.lightEstimationEnabled = true
  ```
- Update lighting in `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)` SceneKit's instance method:

  ```
   func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, 
          updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

       guard let lightEstimate = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.lightEstimate 
       else { return } 
       spotLightNode.light?.intensity = lightEstimate.ambientIntensity
   }
  ```